Enable access to BLOB within Azure Storage account via SAS token URL
I have a requirement where I need to generate a PDF file, upload the same to Azure Storage BLOB, construct a link with SAS token using account level key and embed this link in an email sent out to user.
I am using spring boot stack along with spring-cloud-azure-starter-storage-blob dependency to generate SAS token URL. But when user tries to access URL over internet, it fails with "AuthorizationFailure" error code. I believe this is due to the fact that "public network access" is disabled completely or enabled only from select VNETs and N/Ws. Only when I add my IP explicitly to firewall, does it allow me to access link.
What is the best practice to allow access to BLOB using SAS link? Since users need access from INTERNET, I don't think enabling access from specific IP ranges will work. So is the only option to enable access from all N/Ws but disable anonymous access on container and/or BLOB?

I think this is rather obvious and you correctly understand this. If user has to access a file from any location then you cannot block any location. If user has to log in or has to have shared key then obviously you should disable anonymous access.


What is the best practice to allow access to BLOB using SAS link?Since users need access from INTERNET, I don't think enabling access from specific IP ranges will work. So is the only option to enable access from all N/Ws but disable anonymous access on container and/or BLOB?

To allow access to Azure Storage Blob using a SAS link, here is the recommended options.

You can enable access from selected virtual networks and IP addresses in firewalls and virtual networks section in storage account that you trust, such as your organization's network IP range or the IP range of specific networks of your users, or VNet range, to access the Blob privately with a SAS over the internet.


The above method will only allow users who are within the same network range to access the blob using SAS over the internet.

2.Use a private endpoint: You can create a private endpoint for Azure Storage account, which will allow you to access the Blob over a private connection instead of the public internet. This is a more secure option as it does not expose Blob to the public internet.
Reference:  Configure network access to Azure Storage
Use private endpoints for Azure Storage

Thanks for your responses. But the requirement is that users should be able to access this link over internet. So private endpoint is not an option then right?

If the user wants to access a URL over the internet, the only options are selecting virtual networks and IP addresses. You need to add user network IP ranges.
